CICD start trigger also starting pipeline multiple times
I'm using Github Actions to deploy Synapse from dev to test.
I have triggers in Synapse which I stop then start within the yml file, like:
name: Start Synapse Trigger
run: |
az synapse trigger start --name "triggername" --workspace-name "workspacename"

The trigger is a tumbling window, every 15 mins starting from 00:00.
When this is called in Github, it starts the trigger (as expected) but also actually starts the pipeline the trigger is linked to regardless of the time.
But I only want the pipelines to run at 00, 15, 45. The main issue is it runs multiple times which defeats the point of having a tumbling window.
How can I stop the pipeline starting?
I've got the offset to -00:15:00 on the trigger too btw

On the trigger, I removed the self dependency with the -00:15:00 offset and changed the concurrency to 1, so it still triggers but only once now which is okay.
